# android multiple fragments communicating to the activity through the same interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, fragment, communication

I am working on an application that I expect to migrate to multiple platforms.  To facilitate the porting, I'm using `Fragments` to streamline the process.  So what I have right now is a single `Activity` and several `fragments`. In one case I have several instances of the same `fragment`, with different data. Obviously each of these instances of the same fragment will use the same interface functions.

I've added the parameter "tag" to the interface function to identify each instance of fragment (using the tag used in creating the fragment).  I guess one could also use the `resource ID`.

**My question**:  Is this a good way to do this?  Is there a better or more accepted method?

Activity code snippet:

```
public class SailboatRaceActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements SR_CommandsFragment.OnSR_CommandsSelectedListener,
    SR_SubCommands_Fragment.OnSR_SubCommandsSelectedListener,
    FleetListFragment.FleetList_WidthChange,
    FleetListFragment.FleetListChange,
    FleetScoringFragment.OnFS_SelectedListener,
    FleetSpinnerFragment.FleetSpinner_Selection {
// State Variables
private int mSubCommandPositon;
private int mCommandPosition;
private int mFleetSelection;
private int mFleetListColumnWidth = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSubCommandPositon = savedInstanceState.getInt("mSubCommandPositon");
        mCommandPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("mCommandPosition");
        mFleetSelection = savedInstanceState.getInt("mFleetSelection");
        mFleetListColumnWidth = savedInstanceState.getInt("mFleetListColumnWidth");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.sailboat_race_layout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
}

public void onSR_CommandSelected(int position) {
    SR_SubCommands_Fragment SR_SubCFrag = (SR_SubCommands_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.subcommands);
    mCommandPosition = position;
    if (SR_SubCFrag != null) {
        SR_SubCFrag.update_SR_subcommands(position);
        SR_SubCFrag.ChangeListViewWidth(mFleetListColumnWidth);
    }
}

public void onSR_SubCommandSelected(int position) {
    mSubCommandPositon = position;
    FleetScoringFragment FSFrag = (FleetScoringFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fleet_scoring);
    if (FSFrag != null) {
        FSFrag.update_commands(mCommandPosition, mSubCommandPositon);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("mSubCommandPositon", mSubCommandPositon);
    outState.putInt("mCommandPosition", mCommandPosition);
    outState.putInt("mFleetSelection", mFleetSelection);
    outState.putInt("mFleetListColumnWidth", mFleetListColumnWidth);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void FleetList_WidthChange(int width) {
    mFleetListColumnWidth = width;
    // can we set width of other two lists
    SR_SubCommands_Fragment SR_SubCFrag = (SR_SubCommands_Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.subcommands);
    if (SR_SubCFrag != null) {

        SR_SubCFrag.ChangeListViewWidth(width);
    }
    SR_CommandsFragment SR_CFrag = (SR_CommandsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.commands);
    if (SR_CFrag != null) {

        SR_CFrag.ChangeListViewWidth(width);
    }
}

@Override
public void FleetListChange(int position) {
    FleetScoringFragment FSFrag = (FleetScoringFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fleet_scoring);
    if (FSFrag != null) {
        mFleetSelection = position;
        FSFrag.update_FleetScoringList(position);
    }
    FleetScoringHeaderFragment FSHFrag = (FleetScoringHeaderFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.scoring_header);
    if (FSHFrag != null) {
        mFleetSelection = position;
        FSHFrag.update_FleetScoringHeader(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onFS_Selected(int position) {


}

@Override
public void FSpinner_selection(int selection, String tag) {
    int fs = selection;
    String thistag =tag;
    // do something
}
```

The FSpinner_selection interface is the one I'm working on.  I set this implementation just to check if the data was valid.

FleetSpinner snippet:

```
public class FleetSpinnerFragment extends Fragment  {
private int nPresentFleetPosition;
public ArrayList<FleetItem> mListArray = new ArrayList<FleetItem>();
FleetSpinnerAdapter adapter;
FleetSpinner_Selection mCallback;
Spinner spinner;
String tag;


public interface FleetSpinner_Selection {
    public void FSpinner_selection(int selection, String tag);
}

public FleetSpinnerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (FleetSpinner_Selection) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement FSpinner_Selection");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        nPresentFleetPosition = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<Fleet.fleetbit.length;i++) {
            mListArray.add(Fleet.fleetbit[i]);
        }
    } else {
        nPresentFleetPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("nPresentFleetPosition");
        ArrayList temp = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("thisFleetList");
        mListArray.addAll(temp);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("nPresentFleetPosition", nPresentFleetPosition);
    ArrayList<FleetItem>  temp = new ArrayList<FleetItem>();
    for (int i =0 ; i< adapter.getCount();i++){
        temp.add(adapter.getItem(i));
    }
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("thisFleetList", temp);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = new View(getActivity());

    adapter = new FleetSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fleet_list_item);
    spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.addAll(Fleet.fleetbit);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    tag = getTag();
    spinner.setSelection(nPresentFleetPosition);
    return spinner;
}

public void update_FleetScoringHeader(int position) {

    nPresentFleetPosition = position;
    FrameLayout FLScoringHeader = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scoring_header);
    TextView v1 = (TextView) FLScoringHeader.findViewById(R.id.fleet_list_item_textview);
    v1.setText(Fleet.fleetbit[nPresentFleetPosition].name);
    ImageView v0 = (ImageView) FLScoringHeader.findViewById(R.id.fleet_list_item_icon);
    v0.setImageResource(Fleet.fleetbit[nPresentFleetPosition].id);
}

static class FleetHolder {
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FleetItem temp = (FleetItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        nPresentFleetPosition  = position;
        mCallback.FSpinner_selection(position, tag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

I'm just starting to learn android programming, so this may be a really noob question.

Comment: If I was you, I would probably have a pattern like MVP(Model view presenter) that will separate the logic and some functionality and let the fragments be independent. In your case, it seems like the fragments are very tightly coupled and it would be a hassle to change something. I would use separate fragments hosted by individual activities and have a base Activity and fragment that would act as a medium of supplying the functions.

Comment: I looked up MVP on wikipedia.  I'll need to look elsewhere to understand it better to see if that would help.  My idea was to allow more Spinners and associated scoring fragments on larger screens. The issue I was trying to solve was having 2 or more of these showing the same list. the "//do something useful" in the Activity would tell each spinner what options to remove so no 2 scoring lists could be the same.  Maybe it may be cleaner to just put all the spinners and scoring lists in one fragment and have the Activity instruct what the sizing should be.